# File not found exception in Windows C#

Tags: c#, windows, file, stream

The application runs well the first time when I open a file, read its content and save it. But when I open the same file again, I get a *file-not-found exception*. How do I refresh the stream?

```
FileStream usrFs = null;
try
{
    usrFs = new FileStream(xmlSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
    FileShare.ReadWrite);
}
catch (IOException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("File not found in the specified path");
}
```

#### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MenuItem BasePath="c:\SampleApplication">
```

#### Stack trace

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)    
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)    
at SampleApplication.MainForm.ProcessDocument(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Users\273714\Desktop\CRAFTLite - VSTS\SampleApplication\MainForm.cs:line 179
```

Comment: can You provide us with full track of exception?

Comment: post the `StackTrace` of the exception

Comment: Do you start another process and use it or just close and run it again?

Comment: i dont close the application. i just run it again.
when i close the application and run, i dont get the error.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
    using (FileStream usrFs = new FileStream(xmlSource, FileMode.Open, 
      FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite) 
     {
       ... 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the file, when you have finished reading or writing, `close` the `filestream`...

```
finally
{
   fileStream.Close();
}
```

And  `IOEXCEPTIONS` WILL be of different types and you are just displaying message that file not found. In your case, the exception will **not** be file not found... It will be `file already open by another process`.

Comment: tried adding finally..even then am getting same error while opening previously opened file

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an `IOException` which can be caused by a number of issues.  If you want to check for the file not being found you should check for `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.  Without any additional information, it's difficult to tell exactly what is causing the problem.

One issue is that currently you're not closing the filestream.  You need to call `usrFs.Close()` in a finally method.  Or better yet, use the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword to ensure the file is closed.

```
using( var usrFs = new FileStream(xmlSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite) )
{
    // do things here
}
// usrFs is closed here, regardless of any exceptions.
```

Comment: i get cannot implement type system.io.filestream when i use the above